# Cordova: load epub file in www folder

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, reactjs, cordova-plugins

Time to ask for help; spent too many days of attempting to solve this issue on my own. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I’m running [`react-reader`](https://github.com/gerhardsletten/react-reader) in a web app and it loads epub files across browsers (including Safari) without any issues. But **when the app runs on iOS via Cordova, it no longer loads the epub files**. I’m assuming it might have to do with the way iOS/Cordova handles files, but I’m not an expert in these matters. I did try out different StackOverflow suggestions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880109/phonegap-how-to-access-file-in-www-folder), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937878/cordova-list-all-files-from-application-directory-www), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326272/access-files-from-assets-www-directory), and [this](https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/the-right-location-for-your-cordova-app-files)), to no avail.

All epub files are located in a subfolder: `www/epubs/`

Here’s the `react` code that works on the web app, but not the Cordova app (simplified to the essentials):

```
import React from 'react'
import { EpubView } from 'react-reader'

export default ({ lang, name }) => (
  <EpubView
    url={'epubs/' + lang + '-' + name + '.epub'}
  />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! **One trick that works is to `fs.download` each file from the www folder into Cordova’s persistent file system.** See my [original post](https://github.com/gerhardsletten/react-reader/issues/7#issuecomment-290280054).

First, in Terminal:

1. `npm install cordova-promise-fs`
2. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file --save`
3. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer --save`

Then, in your front-end:

```
import CordovaPromiseFS from 'cordova-promise-fs'

const fs = CordovaPromiseFS({
  persistent: true,
  storageSize: 200 * 1024 * 1024,
  concurrency: 3
})
```

If you use React, the above has to be declared before the component `Class` is created, while the below code should be in its own function inside the component `Class`. See my [GitHub comment](https://github.com/gerhardsletten/react-reader/issues/7#issuecomment-290280054) for more details.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
  cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/epubs/alice.epub',
    // If successful...
    (fileSystem) => {
      const downloadUrl = fileSystem.toURL()
      const localUrl = 'alice.epub' // the filename it is stored as in the device
      fs.download(
        downloadUrl,
        localUrl,
        (progressEvent) => {
          if (progressEvent.loaded && progressEvent.total) {
          console.log('progress', Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100))
        }
      }
    ).then((filedata) => {
      return fs.toInternalURL(localUrl)
    })
    .then((localPath) => {
      this.setState({ epubPath: localPath })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('some error happend', error)
    })
  },
  // If unsuccessful
  (err) => {
    console.log(err)
  }
)
```